# log stash not displaying out put in stdout

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Below is my confi file. and the content of the log.txt is a simple string"abcd" and command is 
**logstash -f "C:\busapps\drsb\gbl0\logstash\7.0.0\bin\pipelines\logstash.conf"**

problem is its not giving any output. simply pipe line is started

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\G703065T1\Desktop\log.log.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
    ignore_older => "0"
  }
}


filter {
        grok {
                match => { "message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
            overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }

}


output {
      stdout {}
    }
```

**output :**

```
Sending Logstash logs to C:/busapps/drsb/gbl0/logstash/7.0.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-03-14T18:20:49,988][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-03-14T18:20:50,004][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.0.0"}
[2020-03-14T18:20:57,727][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x7f28c3fd run>"}
[2020-03-14T18:20:58,370][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2020-03-14T18:20:58,482][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2020-03-14T18:20:58,513][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2020-03-14T18:20:59,130][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

what could the issue ?

Comment: Change your path to use forward slashes and try again, `path => "C:/Users/G703065T1/Desktop/log.log.txt"`.

Comment: yes i did that still the same .
this is my logstash forum link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/log-stash-not-showing-output-in-stdout/223610/7

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try to use a parses:

```
input{
  file{
    path=>"C:\Users\G703065T1\Desktop\log.log.txt"start_position=>"beginning"sincedb_path=>"NUL"ignore_older=>"0"
  }
}filter{
  grok{
    match=>{
      "message"=>"%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    }overwrite=>[
      "message"
    ]
  }
}output{
  { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , http://dpaste.com/1JSAZJ0 
for the above input 
http://dpaste.com/37QC25K this is the out put. log stash is starting and immediately shutting down

Comment: and to my surprise , when i changed the content of the input file to simple "abcd" , still the output is the same !

Answer (score 0):

```
input
{


stdin{}

}

filter{
  grok{
    match => {"message"=>"%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}"}
    overwrite => ["message"]
  }
}
output
{


  stdout{}

}
```

for some reason above config file solved the problem. for past 2 days i have been testing with various config files. i must have tested above some point of timefor sure . but for some reason it had not worked then and its working now. 
i am giving input in std in and getting output from stdout